# Definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Well, I know that the derivative of a function $f(x)$is defined this way:

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

And it's pretty clear that the expression inside the limit will approach the tangent line at a given point. I know that this is the **definition** of derivative. However, we can't `define` this to be equals the tangent line at a given point. So how do we know that this limit will in fact be equal the slope of the function?

Answer (score 1):

It will be arbitrarily close to it. To get rid of ambiguities, we need to define derivative in a different way: Suppose $\epsilon > 0 $ If we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $| \Delta x | < \delta$

$$  \text{Then it follows that} \; \; \; | \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} - L | < \epsilon$$

And we call $L = \frac{df}{dx} $

Comment: This does not prove that the derivative is equals to the tangent line

Comment: Don't we have an ambiguity since $|\Delta x|$ can approach zero from the negative or positive side and thus give different results? What is the case for f(x)=0 for x < 0 and f(x) = x for x$\ge$0?

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a curve at a point on it's graph, is the gradient of the tangent at that point. Now if you draw the graph of $f$ you will see that the expression inside the limit approaches the gradient of the tangent at the point $x$ when $\Delta x$ tends to zero.

The derivative at a point of a function is a general concept that is defined in a abstract way without considering the graph of the function. It so happens that the geometrical interpretation of the derivate at a point is the gradient of the tangent drawn at that graph.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your concern correctly, you want to know how the definition of the derivative relates to the intuitive notion of what a tangent is.

Let's assume that we are analysing a twice continuously differentiable function $f(x)$ at the point $x=a$ and that $f''(a)$ is positive.

Intuition tells us that a line $\ell(x)$ that is tangent to the graph of $f$ at the given point $a$ should be such that

1. $\ell(a) = f(a)$ and
2. It somehow "sits" on the graph of $f$, that is, it stays on top or below the graph in a neighborhood of $a$ (This may not be true if $f''(a)$ is $0$, see below).

Now, take $\ell(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$. We will show that it meets the required conditions. Condition 1. is immediate from the definition.

For condition 2., we know that, by continuity, there should be a neighborhood $V$ of $a$ where $f''(a)>0$. Moreover, $f'(x)$ is increasing in $V$. The line $\ell$ in this case sits below the graph. Indeed, if $x >a$ lies in the neighborhood $V$,
$$\begin{align}
     & f(x) - \ell(x) \ge 0\\
\iff & f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a) \ge 0 \\
\iff & \frac{f(x)- f(a)}{(x-a)}  - f'(a) \ge 0 \\
\iff & f'(c)  - f'(a) \ge 0 \\
\end{align}$$
by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), with $c$ lying in the interval $[a,x]$. The last inequality is true because $f'$ is increasing in V. A similar argument shows that $f(x) \ge \ell(x)$ for an $x$ in $V$ with $x<a$.

If $f''(a)$ is negative, you can get the same result, but this time with $\ell$ lying on top of the graph of $f$.

The case $f''(a)=0$ is somewhat different, as you may have something like this: [image: image taken from the web]